# How to improve algorithm efficiency for nested loop

Tags: ruby, algorithm, loops, iteration

Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (from the left) that add up to form the sum.

For example, given:

```
sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)
```

`[5, 5]` (at indices `[1, 5]` of `[10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5]`) add up to `10`, and `[3, 7]` (at indices `[3, 4]`) add up to `10`. Among them, the entire pair `[3, 7]` is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer.

Here is my code:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s)
  result = []
  i = 0
  while i < ints.length - 1
    j = i+1
    while j < ints.length
      result << [ints[i],ints[j]] if ints[i] + ints[j] == s
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  puts result.to_s
  result.min
end
```

It works, but is too inefficient, taking 12000 ms to run. The nested loop is the problem of inefficiency. How could I improve the algorithm?

Comment: Try with https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-combination, find which pairs returns the sum, then look for their index in the original array.

Comment: It takes 66ms for me. Are you running on a much larger set?

Answer (score 6):

- Have a `Set` of numbers you have seen, starting empty
- Look at each number in the input list
- Calculate which number you would need to add to it to make up the sum
- See if that number is in the set
- If it is, return it, and the current element
- If not, add the current element to the set, and continue the loop
- When the loop ends, you are certain there is no such pair; the task does not specify, but returning `nil` is likely the best option

Should go superfast, as there is only a single loop. It also terminates as soon as it finds the first matching pair, so normally you wouldn't even go through every element before you get your answer.

As a style thing, using `while` in this way is very unRubyish. In implementing the above, I suggest you use `ints.each do |int| ... end` rather than `while`.

EDIT: As Cary Swoveland commented, for a weird reason I thought you needed indices, not the values.

Comment: I don't think the OP needs the indices, just the numbers, Had you read it that way I expect you would have suggested what I have done in my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Ah indeed, not sure why I thought indices were wanted :/ Yeah, your code is what I was trying to get OP to try to write :D

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'set'

def sum_pairs(arr, target)
  s = Set.new
  arr.each do |v|
    return [target-v, v] if s.include?(target-v)
    s << v
  end
  nil
end

sum_pairs [10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10
  #=> [3, 7]
sum_pairs [10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 99
  #=> nil
```

I've used [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) methods to speed `include?` lookups (and, less important, to save only unique values).

Answer (score 1):

Try below, as it is much more readable.

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s)
  ints.each_with_index.map do |ele, i|
    if ele < s
      rem_arr = ints.from(i + 1)
      rem = s - ele
      [ele, rem] if rem_arr.include?(rem)
    end
  end.compact.last
end
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still a beginner, I don't understand what `end.compact.last` does. My understanding would be with that line, we don't have to define a variable to store the `.map` result of the rem_arr, right?

Comment: Also, why is the `.from` method undefined?

Answer (score 0):

One liner (the fastest?)

```
ary = [10, 0, 8, 5, 2, 7, 3, 5, 5]
sum = 10

def sum_pairs(ary, sum)
  ary.map.with_index { |e, i|  [e, i] }.combination(2).to_a.keep_if { |a| a.first.first + a.last.first == sum }.map { |e| [e, e.max { |a, b| a.last <=> b.last }.last] }.min { |a, b| a.last <=> b.last }.first.map{ |e| e.first }
end
```

Yes, it's not really readable, but if you add methods step by step starting from `ary.map.with_index { |e, i|  [e, i] }` it's easy to understand how it works.